# How do I inject the simple auth session into an adapter?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-simple-auth

I have an adapter that queries a url using user specific data. I need a way to get data from the simple auth session to the adapter.

I tried to inject the session into the adapter
Adapter

```
session: Ember.inject.service('session'),
```

But this is throwing an error

> Error while processing route: videos.index Attempting to inject an
>   unknown injection: `service:session` Error:
>   Attempting to inject an unknown injection:
>   `service:session`

Edit:

In the adapter I can retrieve the user data via the container.

Adapter:

```
var container = this.get('container');
var currentUser = container.lookup('session:withCurrentUser');
console.log('currentUser ID', currentUser.get('secure.userData.id'));
```

Would this be the recommended way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

First, you'd only need

```
session: Ember.inject.service(),
```

Ember knows from the variable name that you need the 'session' service.

Anyhow, I'd recommend to create an initializer where you inject your session into the adapter.

```
//initializer/adapter.js
App.inject('adapter', 'session', 'service:session');
```